# Rails 3.1, why I get ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute in spec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rspec2

I am trying to create a `Student` record in a test, like this:

```
student= Student.create!(:work_phone => "1234567890")
```

but I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: work_phone
```

However, `work_phone` is defined in the `Student` model, and migrated.

Here is the `Student`model:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_length_of :work_phone, :is => 10, :message => 'must be 10 digits, excluding special characters such as spaces and dashes. No extension or country code allowed.', :if => Proc.new{|o| !o.work_phone.blank?}

  attr_accessible:work_phone

end
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Are you getting this error only in your test environment. More specifically, when you run tests using

```
rake spec
```

This could be happening becase you have not run your migrations on your test environments.
You can either do,

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

or after having having run migrations on your development like below.

```
rake db:migrate
rake db:test:prepare
```

Comment: Yes, that's why right, Also, I need to add attr_accessor:work_phone to the model, thanks

Comment: Preparing the test database with `rake db:test:prepare` fixed it for me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Only adding attr_accessor:work_phone to model also works.

Comment: I suspect it worked because it you now have a attribute on the model. But it might just be saving it on that instance only. Try reloading the model and see if you can still find the value there.

 If you intention is to make sure it gets saved to the database as well, then you will have to make sure the database schema to which you are saving the records also has a column for the same. (which means to make sure you have run migrations against your test database in this case).